# Making predictions in AutoML Natural Language UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I've been testing the Natural Language UI functionality and created a model for Single-Label classification. To train the model I used a csv with two columns, the first column has the text and the second has the label.

Then I get to the "Test & Use" tab to perform predictions. I upload a csv file into GS and when I try to select it I get the message that "*Invalid file type, only following file types allowed: pdf, tif, tiff"*

I was wondering whether I can use a csv file similar to when I trained the model.

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/predict#online_prediction), you can't do batch prediction from the UI.
You need to use the [API's batchPredict method](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/predict#batch_prediction) to do so.

> If you would like to use your model to do high-throughput asynchronous prediction on a corpus of documents you can use the batchPredict method. The batch prediction methods require you to specify input and output URIs that point to locations in Cloud Storage buckets.
> The input URI points to a CSV or JSONL file, which specifies the content to analyze

Example:

```
gs://folder/text1.txt
gs://folder/text2.pdf
```